# Prism 6 with dynamically load module

Tags: c#, prism

I have a problem with `Prism 6` dynamically loading module from a folder. I utilised the approach introduced in [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2013/08/06/prism-dynamically-discover-and-load-modules-at-runtime.aspx) to find and load module from a given folder. My case is as follow:

I have `ModuleA`, which needs to include **ProjectA.dll**. Now if I put **ModuleA.dll** and **ProjectA.dll** in the folder (named Modules, the path is bin\Debug\Modules) and then run the code, everything is fine. `ModuleA` can use the function in **ProjectA.dll** very well.

If I run the whole program first and then copy **ModuleA.dll** and **ProjectA.dll** into the folder (bin\Debug\Modules), the **ModuleA.dll** cannot load **ProjectA.dll** and then an error occurs.

If I copy **ProjectA.dll** to bin\Debug\ and then copy **ModuleA.dll** to bin\Debug\Modules, everything is fine again.

If I copy **ProjectA.dll** to bin\Debug\Modules\, then run the program and then copy **ModuleA.dll** to bin\Debug\Modules\, **ProjectA.dll** still cannot be found and an exception occurred again.

Can anyone help to see what is wrong and what shall I do to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: Is ProjectA a bootstrapper?

Comment: No, it is just a normal project including some classes that are used by other projects/modules as well.